# how to change the type of items in the list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list that consists of elements of type "string".

```
li = ['1 ', '2', '3 ', '4', '5 ', '6', '7 ']
```

I need to change the type of each element on the "int". use cycles are not desirable.

Comment: What does the last sentence mean?

Comment: @hivert: well, not quite because those ones are nested, but I'm sure this has been asked before. A lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the [map function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), which returns a generator and so does lazy casting in this case (cast only when you need a new element from the list):

```
li = map(int, li)
```

With your example (and Python 3)

```
>>> li = ['1 ', '2', '3 ', '4', '5 ', '6', '7 ']
>>> map(int, li)
<map object at 0xffe3ed0c>
>>> list(map(int, li))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> for elem in map(int, li):
...     print(elem)
...
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

---

As pointed by @hivert, `map` is [some kind of deprecated in the Python community](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/). You could use a list comprehension or a generator instead:

```
[int(x) for x in li]  # create the full list directly
(int(n) for n in li)  # create a generator (note parentheses instead of brackets)
```

Comment: The OP is using Python 3.  (Or at least that's how it's tagged.)

Comment: I like this solution. It's clean!

Comment: Worth noting: this returns a generator, not a list.

Comment: +1 because lazily casting the values strikes me as more appropriate than bulk converting an entire data structure.

Comment: @DSM yeah but it doesn't matter, see kojiro explanation (I allowed myself to rewrite the idea in my answer)

Comment: Also from PEP 279 "Comments from GvR:  filter and map should die and be subsumed into list comprehensions, not grow more variants." So they are kind of deprecated. List comprehension are better.

Comment: @hivert I've updated my post to add a precision about it.

Answer (score 3):

You can cast it using this code:

```
 li = [int(x) for x in li]
```

it will create new list with each element in the old list but with casting to int.

Comment: Explain why this works.

Comment: @BleedingFingers it will create new list with each element in the old list but with cast to int.

Comment: Please [edit] it into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) together with the `int` type:

```
list_of_ints = [int(n) for n in li]
```

---

If you don't necessarily need all the items in the list, a [generator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) might be more appropriate. This will avoid evaluating each item until it is needed.

```
int_generator = (int(n) for n in li) # Note the () instead of []
```

This is equivalent to `map(int, li)` but (IMO) more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `int()` in a list comprehension:

```
li = ['1 ', '2', '3 ', '4', '5 ', '6', '7 ']
ints = [int(n) for n in li]
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to cast the string to an int. Python does this with the `int()` function:

```
li = ['1 ', '2', '3 ', '4', '5 ', '6', '7 ']

li_int = [int(x) for x in li]

print li_int

>>>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

After running this you have a new list that contains all the values but as ints.

If you want to change the items in li without creating a new list just do:

```
li = ['1 ', '2', '3 ', '4', '5 ', '6', '7 ']

li = [int(x) for x in li]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using map function

```
li = map(int, li)
```